# Why is the # character duplicated in footnotes?

Tags: footnotes, minted

I've run into a weird issue related to footnotes.

When I compile the document I pasted below, the "regular" #import statement is shown exactly as it appears in the source code. However, when I use the exact same bit of text in the footnote, an additional # is inserted with no apparent reason, causing "##import" to be shown in the produced document.

Can someone enlighten me as to what is going on here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle[glsl]{colorful}
\usemintedstyle[c]{colorful}
\usemintedstyle[cpp]{colorful}
\usemintedstyle[bash]{colorful}

\title{mintedtest}
\author{Me}
\date{August 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Some text \mintinline{c}{#include something} More text \footnote{Some text \mintinline{c}{#include something} More text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fn 1. of the documentation: *For example, `\mintinline` works in footnotes! The main exception is when the code contains the percent % or hash # characters, or unmatched curly braces.*

Comment: Use `\#` to typeset an octothorpe, not a bare `#` (which is a special character to TeX). (Edit: Maybe I don't understand how `\mintinline` works. @AlanMunn seems better informed.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Escaping the character doesn't work. The result in my case becomes "\#include"

Comment: @AlanMunn Well, I guess that explains it.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. (See my update on the comment you responded to. I really had *no idea* what the `minted` package does. Sorry about the noise.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known limitation of the `\mintinline` command which is mentioned in Fn 1 of the documentation:

> For example, `\mintinline` works in footnotes! The main exception is when the code contains the percent `%` or hash `#` characters, or unmatched curly braces.

Since the `minted` authors are clearly aware of it, I suspect it's not an issue that they are planning to solve.